# How to create test object in my model?

Tags: django

How to create test object in my model? I need to create 200 objects (automatically)

```
class Data(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_good = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    reminder = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: You could use fixtures if the schema doesn't change that often

Comment: It will help if you explain how this data is used and it's purpose. You could also script it if you need varying test-objects.

Comment: This Data is used in my views function to calculate reminder time. I need to create 200 objects and test my view function

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [factory_boy](https://github.com/dnerdy/factory_boy). I think this might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try some [fixture generation app](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/fixtures/).

Answer (score 0):

The django's *official* approach to create test data are fixtures, you can either write them yourself or use any fixture creation tool like autofixture.

What I've found with fixtures is that if your model changes, you need to manually change your fixture, this is very error prone and a little painful. There are a lot of questions on testing with several models in django, you may want to check this ones:

- [Unit-testing tightly-coupled models in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029946/unit-testing-tightly-coupled-models-in-django/14085917#14085917)
- [Unit Testing with Django Models and a lot of relations involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874071/unit-testing-with-django-models-and-a-lot-of-relations-involved/11960345#11960345)

And if you want to go deeper with testing in django, here is another very good one

- [What are the best practices for testing "different layers" in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543117/what-are-the-best-practices-for-testing-different-layers-in-django)